# Generate beta-binomial distribution from existing vector

Tags: r, distribution

Is it possible to/how can I generate a beta-binomial distribution from an existing vector?

My ultimate goal is to generate a beta-binomial distribution from the below data and then obtain the 95% confidence interval for this distribution.

My data are body condition scores recorded by a veterinarian. The values of body condition range from 0-5 in increments of 0.5. It has been suggested to me [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442678/confidence-interval-for-beta-binomial-distribution-with-restricted-range) that my data follow a beta-binomial distribution, discrete values with a restricted range.

```
set1 <- as.data.frame(c(3,3,2.5,2.5,4.5,3,2,4,3,3.5,3.5,2.5,3,3,3.5,3,3,4,3.5,3.5,4,3.5,3.5,4,3.5))
colnames(set1) <- "numbers"
```

I see that there are multiple functions which appear to be able to do this, `betabinomial()` in `VGAM` and `rbetabinom()` in `emdbook`, but my stats and coding knowledge is not yet sufficient to be able to understand and implement the instructions provided on the function help pages, at least not in a way that has been helpful for my intended purpose yet.

Comment: I would recommend that you first check documentation and examples of the package documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.1-2/topics/betabinomial

Comment: Also this http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/rmutil/html/BetaBinom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look at the distribution of your variables, y-axis is the probability:

```
x1 = set1$numbers*2
h = hist(x1,breaks=seq(0,10))
bp = barplot(h$counts/length(x1),names.arg=(h$mids+0.5)/2,ylim=c(0,0.35))
```

[image]

You can try to fit it, but you have too little data points to estimate the 3 parameters need for a beta binomial. Hence I fix the probability so that the mean is the mean of your scores, and looking at the distribution above it seems ok:

```
library(bbmle)
library(emdbook)
library(MASS)

mtmp <- function(prob,size,theta) {
-sum(dbetabinom(x1,prob,size,theta,log=TRUE))
}

m0 <- mle2(mtmp,start=list(theta=100),
data=list(size=10,prob=mean(x1)/10),control=list(maxit=1000))
THETA=coef(m0)[1]
```

We can also use a normal distribution:

```
normal_fit = fitdistr(x1,"normal")
MEAN=normal_fit$estimate[1]
SD=normal_fit$estimate[2]
```

Plot both of them:

```
lines(bp[,1],dbetabinom(1:10,size=10,prob=mean(x1)/10,theta=THETA),
col="blue",lwd=2)
lines(bp[,1],dnorm(1:10,MEAN,SD),col="orange",lwd=2)
legend("topleft",c("normal","betabinomial"),fill=c("orange","blue"))
```

I think you are actually ok with using a normal estimation and in this case it will be:

```
normal_fit$estimate
    mean       sd 
6.560000 1.134196
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer and patience. It is much appreciated. I know it can be frustrating explaining things in detail for less knowledgeable people sometimes

Comment: Hi @PatTaggart, no problem at all. Hope it helps in your data analysis :)